# Why are tables grayed out and non-deletable in Access?

Tags: ms-access, datatables

I inherited an Access database where the (local) tables seem to be all grayed out, at least the existing ones. They only show up when I check "Show system objects" but many of these are not system tables. How can I "un-system" them? When right-clicking and going to Properties, it shows as hidden with the check box disabled. And yet if I turn off "show hidden objects" they're still there.

EDIT: Just to clarify, user defined tables are showing up as system tables and are "hidden" and I'm unable to uncheck the hidden box. This is a COPY of the backend of a split database, on my local hard drive and no one else has it open.

[image]
[image]

Comment: [MS Access 2007: View hidden tables](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/database/view_hiddentbls2007.php)

Answer (score 0):

This would suggest that the database is being opened as read only.

It is also possible that you are using a older version of Access, and the database and tables in question have used "newer" features. In Access 2010, they introduced table macros. This feature allows you to attach triggers and stored procedure code to tables. However, if you open a 2010 database that used these features with say 2007, then everything will be set as read only. So, this is either some file permissions are attached to this file, or you are opening the accDB file with a "older" or "previous" version of access that does not support the features used in those table(s).

I would create a new blank database, and then import all of the tables etc. into that newer database. That should give you update rights.